# Variable value is not copied out of a callback's scope

Tags: kotlin, retrofit

This is a very basic POST callback using Retrofit. After calling my Rest API the **response.code** is 200 and the **response.body** contains the result I need and is not null. The log verifies this. For some reason the reference contained in **response.body** is not coppied in the **loginResult** variable and the last if statement is always true. I suspect this has something to do with the callback not being able to access the **loginResult** variable but I am not sure.

```
var loginResult: AuthenticationRequestResult? = null
    
        api.authenticateUser(AuthenticationRequestData(username, password)).enqueue(object : Callback<AuthenticationRequestResult> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthenticationRequestResult>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e(TAG,t.message,t)
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthenticationRequestResult>, response: Response<AuthenticationRequestResult>) {
            loginResult = response.body() as AuthenticationRequestResult
            Log.d(TAG,"response code:" + response.code())
            Log.e(TAG,"Response body: " + response.body())
            Log.e(TAG,"Response body error: " + response.body()?.error)
        }
    })

    if(loginResult == null) {Log.e(TAG,"LoginResult is null")}
```

Comment: Move `if(loginResult == null) {Log.e(TAG,"LoginResult is null")}` inside the callback. The callback is called in the future so you won't have immediate results in the function that calls it.

Comment: True, I just realised that the callback actually runs in an unsync task.

Comment: Callbacks are always asynchronous. Otherwise, the function would just return something.